# Not able to create Custom button in pop up activity

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have made custom buttons before and they work just fine. But something is wrong in this one. It does not take up the drawable I specified . Activity layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_continue"
    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    android:onClick="goToStart"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="86dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/dialogue_textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom Button(button_continue.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_continue_pressed"/>

<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_continue_focused"/>

<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_continue_enabled"/>

</selector>
```

I don't think that it really has much to do with the activity file but still :

```
package com.mycompany.whackamole;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.mycompany.whackamole.GameView.*;

public class Pop extends AppCompatActivity{

int width , height ;
TextView textView;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.pop_activity);

    width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout(width , (int)(height * 0.5));

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogue_textView);
    setScoreText();
    intent = getIntent();
}

public void goToStart(View view) {
    Intent boo = new Intent(this , StartActivity.class);
    startActivity(boo);
}

private void setScoreText() {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf("Time's up! Your score was " + score));
}

}
```

Great if you could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml file change:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_continue"
```

in place of:

```
android:drawable="@drawable/button_continue"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have set the wrong attribute in the layout file. It should be android:background and not drawable.